# Common repository maven best practices

Tags: maven, parent-pom

If my company has an artifactory repository set up, what is the best way to ensure all projects can access it?

Currently all repository information is in a master pom project (it also contains stuff other than repo info). Then any other projects have that master pom as the parent to inherit from. Because the projects are independent, we have to use the `relativePath` property and ensure the master pom is in the correct relative directory.

Is there a better way?

Comment: I've always set it up inside the corporate Maven distribution/install `settings.xml`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the settings.xml you have to configure the access to the company repository manager and in your corporate pom you have to setup up the distributionManagement.